# How to get the value from the multiple div to the Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, sharepoint

I have issue in storing the value from div id to local varible in javascript.
I have a table which generate a dynamic div tags. So somehow using the table Id i can get the dynamic div tags in the variable. I can see those div tags using the alert(variable.innerHTML). I need the values from that inner HTML.

Following is my alert output.

I need to get the values of dates so that i can find the number of days.

```
<iframe src="javascript:false;" id="FilterIframe33" name="FilterIframe33" style="display:none" height="0" width="0" filterlink="?">
</iframe>
<table summary="Active Projects " o:webquerysourcehref="url;XMLDATA=1&amp;RowLimit=0&amp;View={A6F61185-B2B2-4A3C-8401-FDCCA1D9673D}" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" dir="none" onmouseover="                  EnsureSelectionHandler(event,this,33)                " cellpadding="1" id="{CD556AFD-0460-4DA1-8103-07AFB43D0847}-{A6F61185-B2B2-4A3C-8401-FDCCA1D9673D}" class="ms-listviewtable ms-basictable                  " xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" handledeleteinit="true">
<thead>
<tr valign="top" class="ms-viewheadertr ms-vhltr">
<th nowrap="" scope="col" onmouseover="OnChildColumn(this)" class="ms-vh2">
<div sortable="" sortdisable="" filterdisable="" filterable="FALSE" filterdisablemessage="" name="Project_x0020_Name" ctxnum="33" displayname="Proj...-presence-disconnected-10x10x32" title="" showofflinepawn="1" src="/_layouts/15/images/spimn.png?rev=23" alt="No presence information" sip="email.iD" id="imn_7094,type=smtp"></span>
</a>
</span>
<span class="ms-noWrap ms-imnSpan"><a href="#" onclick="IMNImageOnClick(event);return false;" class="ms-imnlink" tabindex="-1">
<img name="imnmark" class="ms-hide" title="" showofflinepawn="1" src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif?rev=23" alt="" sip="emailID" id="imn_7095,type=smtp">
</a>
<a class="ms-subtleLink" onclick="GoToLinkOrDialogNewWindow(this);return false;" href="/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?ID=11">Brad Griggs
</a>
</span>
</span></td><td class="ms-vb2">
<div align="right">61 %</div>
</td><td class="ms-vb2">
<div><img src="/SiteAssets/On%20Track.png"></div>
</td><td class="ms-vb2">Jody Standifer</td>
<td class="ms-vb2">
<nobr>10/25/2016</nobr>
</td>
<td class="ms-vb2">
<nobr>8/11/2017</nobr>
</td><td class="ms-vb2">
<nobr>4/21/2017 2:30 PM</nobr>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your dates seem to have a common class so get the tags using `$('.ms-vb2')` then get the first child's innerHtml.

Comment: Can you help me with the code? It will be much appreciated..

Comment: You provide your code and we will give you assistance. If you do not have any code then do some research. 

Try jQuery. Beginner friendly. 

1. https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/ -- Learn about selecting elements with a selector.
2. https://api.jquery.com/each/ -- Learn about looping through a collection of elements returned by a jQuery selector.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery as the comments suggest. you can also stick to plain javascript if your audience is on atleast IE9. surely won't work if this is NOT on a local intranet company application, then learn jquery, it will help you to do things quicker in the long run.

i would get rid of the "nobr" usage first. use css to handle whitespace.

the values in your class=ms-vb2 don't seem to be consistent, in that, they are not always dates so careful with using the class selector here.

```
var n = document.getElementsByClassName("ms-vb2").length;

    for (var i=0, n; i < n; i++) {       
        console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("ms-vb2").item(i).firstChild.nodeValue)
    }
```

Comment: As a side note, `document.querySelectorAll(".ms-vb2")`works even on IE8